# Cannot upload file to firebase storage android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a pdf file from my phone to firebase storage. I can select the required file from my phone but cannot upload it. I have also checked the rules of my firebase storage to allow read and write. 
My code is:

```
package com.example.agrismart;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class UploadFile extends AppCompatActivity {



    EditText et;
    Button b1,b2;

    //the firebase objects for storage and database
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

    Uri pdfuri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploads);
        b1=findViewById(R.id.buttonUploadFile);
        b2=findViewById(R.id.ViewUploads);
        et = findViewById(R.id.editTextFileName);

        //getting firebase objects
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UploadFile.this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    selectPdf();
                }
                else{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UploadFile.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},9);
                }
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(pdfuri!=null) uploadFile(pdfuri);
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(UploadFile.this,"s22",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void uploadFile(Uri pdfuri) {
        StorageReference st=storage.getReference();
        st.child("sass").putFile(pdfuri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                String url= taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();


            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode==9 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            selectPdf();
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    public void selectPdf(){
        Intent intent= new Intent();
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,86);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==86 && resultCode ==RESULT_OK && data != null){
            pdfuri=data.getData();
            et.setText(pdfuri.toString());
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(UploadFile.this,"saas",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

After trying to upload the pdf I get sent back to the previous activity. I checked with other sources so my code seems alright.

Comment: First, stop ignoring errors. Try to log `e` from `onFailure()`, do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo It prints ```isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted   accessInfo : 1```